# Creating Polls app form Django

Tags: python, django, forms, django-models, django-forms

Trying to create a form for my polls app.But I am not able to include choices as well for it.I can only add polls right now through admin.
(Its the official django polls app tutorial and i am trying to extend it further by adding a form)

Models.py

```
class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    publish_date = models.DateTimeField('date published',null=True,blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.question_text 

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('polls:index')

class Choice(models.Model):
    question_text = models.ForeignKey(Question,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.choice_text
```

forms.py

```
 class QuestionForm(forms.ModelForm):

    question_text = forms.CharField(required=True)
    publish_date = forms.CharField(required=False)
    choice_text = forms.CharField(required=True)

    class Meta():
        model = Question
        fields = ('question_text','choice_text')
```

View To create Poll

```
class CreatePoll(CreateView):
    redirect_field_name = 'polls/index.html'
    template_name = 'polls/poll_form.html'
    form_class = QuestionForm
    model = Question
```

This is My Form View But the choice entered doesnt get saved.Saw in the admin view too
[image: My Form View Appears Like this But the choice entered doesnt get saved.Saw in the admin view too it was not saved]

[image]

polls_form.html

```
{% extends 'polls/base.html' %}

{% block content %}
<h1>New Post</h1>
<form class="post-form" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
{% csrf_token %}
{{form.as_p}}
<button type="submit" class="save btn btn-primary">Save</button>
</form>
<script>var editor = new MediumEditor('.editable');</script>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Could you also post the `polls/poll_form.html`'s content?

Comment: @slackmart done !

Comment: Your template looks fine(BTW). Given you're inheriting from a `ModelForm`, you do not need to redefine the fields in the form class. It's enough to specify the fields you want to include (in the `Meta` class).

Comment: How do i include the choice_text field which is of model Choice(not question) and also then how do i define the fields which are required or not ?